# Broken Array after pushing new element

Tags: javascript, arrays

So Ive just faced this issue when my array goes broken after I delete last element from it `delete array[key]` and then try to push new one.

So before deleting the element it looks like this:

```
    guests: 
    [{ id: 263457,
        avatar: '...',
        name: 'Moamal' }],
```

After deleting this element it looks like this:

```
guests: [  ]
```

and after pushing new one:

```
    guests: 
    [ ,
     { id: 263459,
       avatar: '...',
       name: 'HalloweenD' } ]
```

and I'm pushing new element to this array like this

```
self.actives.push({ id: 263459,
       avatar: '...',
       name: 'HalloweenD' });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `array.splice(key,1);` to delete the element instead of `delete`.

`delete` removes the element, but keeps an empty slot. Splice removes both the element and the slot.

Comment: To be more precise: `delete` remotes the referenced property but it does not re-enumerate existing array elements since `delete` doesn't know about arrays.